# pptp vpn client close all inside connections

Tags: centos, vpn, pptp

I setup PPTP-VPN-client on my Centos VPS

(guide: http://websistent.com/how-to-configure-a-linux-pptp-vpn-client/ )

when i connect to pptp server from my centos vps all connections(ex ping, SSH-apache webserver) stoped and i can n't connect to my vps.

is there any way to use vpn-client and connect to vps whitout problem?

thanks

Comment: What does your configuration say about split routing?

Comment: I Used This guide: [http://websistent.com/how-to-configure-a-linux-pptp-vpn-client/] my route: `Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
PPTP_IP   hostname         255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
` @kasperd